# Select random object from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, random

I have the following code:

```
$.getJSON('js/questions1.json').done(function(data){
        window.questionnaire = data;
        console.log(window.questionnaire);
        startGame();
    });
```

This brings a json from the server and logs it into a variable. Now after this, I want to select a random question located in the questions.json document:

```
function pickRandomQuestion(){
        window.selectedquestion = window.questionnaire[Math.floor(Math.random * window.questionnaire.length)];
        console.log(window.selectedquestion);
        console.log(window.questionnaire);
    }
```

However, when `console.log()` the selectedquestion variable, nothing comes back, it's undefined. Is there something wrong with my code? I've tripled checked it and I see nothing bad on it, but it might just be my head playing games with me.

Here's how the json looks:

```
"q1" : {
        "question" : "This country is one of the largest wine-producing countries of the world, where wine is grown in every region of the country. Which country is this?",
        "a"        : "France",
        "b"        : "Italy",
        "c"        : "Germany",
        "d"        : "Australia",
        "corrrect" : "b"
    },
    "q2" : {
        "question" : "What is the name for the type of art portrait that deliberately exaggerates a person?",
        "a"        : "Environmental",
        "b"        : "Cartooning",
        "c"        : "Caricature",
        "d"        : "Tribal",
        "corrrect" : "c"
    },
    "q3" : {
        "question" : "Who was the first president of the United States?",
        "a"        : "Abraham Lincoln",
        "b"        : "Ronald Reagan",
        "c"        : "George Washington",
        "d"        : "Barack Obama",
        "corrrect" : "c"
    }...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because `math.random` is function not a property.

Change it to: `Math.random()`

and becuase `window.questionnaire` is an object you can't access it using indexes i.e(0,1,2)

you can do this:

```
function pickRandomQuestion(){
        var obj_keys = Object.keys(window.questionnaire);
        var ran_key = obj_keys[Math.floor(Math.random() *obj_keys.length)];
        window.selectedquestion = window.questionnaire[ran_key];
        console.log(window.selectedquestion);
        console.log(window.questionnaire);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the data randomly whenever you get it from the json:

`data.sort(function() { return .5 - Math.random();});`

```
$.getJSON('js/questions1.json').done(function(data){
    window.questionnaire = data;
    window.questionnaire.sort(function() { return .5 - Math.random();});
    console.log(window.questionnaire);
    startGame();
});
```

Then, in the `pickRandomQuestion()` you can just take the first element in `window.questionnaire`, knowing that it was randomly sorted.

Note: you could also always randomly sort the list inside the `pickRandomQuestion()` routine, but I imagine you might want some logic in there so that the same random question doesn't come up as often as it would randomly, or so at least `pickRandomQuestion()` won't return the same question as the current one.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize your json wasn't coming back as an array. This might not be as useful then :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
function pickRandomQuestion(){
    window.selectedquestion = window.questionnaire['q' + Math.floor(Math.random() * window.questionnaire.length)];
    console.log(window.selectedquestion);
    console.log(window.questionnaire);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `window.questionnaire` will have a `length` property. You probably need to do something like `Object.keys(window.questionnaire).reduce(function (length, key) { return length + (window.questionnaire.hasOwnProperty(key) ? 1 : 0); }, 0)`